# Visual studio 2015 WPF redo localization strings

Tags: wpf, xaml, localization, visual-studio-2015, resharper

I have a WPF/XAML project where someone has started localization but in very messy way.
What i want todo is to restart with the localization. I want to undo (inline) the string from the resource files. Then set the strings back into the code and refactor my way into the new structure.

But i can't find a tool to help me undo the resource files.
I've tried visual localize which can batch inline but not for XAML files.
Also tried resharper here is no bulk support.

Is there a way to quickly covert te resource string back into actual strings?

Comment: what is wrong with resource file based localization?  WPF has an ugly way, I prefer using resource files for localization/globalization every other solution creates a mess IMHO.

Comment: I also want to use a resource files but the names are now not clear.
I want to redo it to choose better names.

Comment: look at the code behind that the resources file creates... can you change that code and have it reflect in resources file?